# Extracting columns from a text file after neglecting few lines of text in starting of the text file

Tags: r, read.table

I need to access the data in the columns from a text file having name "Apure.asc".
I cannot use the read.table or read.csv on it because it contains some extra text in it in the starting which makes it hard for R to open it as a table or a csv file. I also tried using import.asc function from the adehabitat library, but it doesn't seems to work.

The text file looks like as follows:

```
TANKEXE: Sugawara-IHE tank model. Development: D.P. Solomatine
Output to file: D:\Work from Home\Apure53.ASC
Input CAL file: D:\Work from Home\Apure53.CAL  (53 time points)
Input PIN file: D:\Work from Home\g.pin  with values:
      8820.7440,48.7801,0.0215,0.0361,0.0436,0.0050,915.2973,113.4371, 
Calculated error value(s) :  
(3) Weighted root mean squared error        :       21.0927

Time       ObservedCalculated runoff, Water balance
 1,         5.3482,        76.7017,     1027.7425
 2,         4.7455,        67.4817,      954.3219
 3,         3.9938,        58.9400,      884.5183
 4,         3.5208,        51.0347,      818.1752
```

Any suggestions on how to access the column data from such a file.

Comment: Why don't you check the `skip` option in `?read.table`? It allows you to skip a certain amount of lines and then start reading your file.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work,

```
read.csv("Apure.asc", skip=7, strip.white=TRUE) # 7 should match number of non-data, non-blank lines in header
```